# jQuery sortable with table cells in a column

Tags: jquery, selection, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to have cells in a particular column of a table sortable.

http://jsbin.com/ilodi4

The problem is that the current code makes the whole row sortable instead of just make the cells sortable. Cells for a given column should be vertically sortable and only in their particular column.

Is there a way to assign a unique class to a table column through jQuery perhaps?

Comment: http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table.html handle something similar - but does not have multiple columns in the table.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because it shouldn't have been an "answer" in the first place. I hope this doesn't delete any comment you're interested in. I think having the answer is keeping other people from answering.